# Zendesk Talk Links

Tags: html, zendesk

Weird question for you, in html we have links that can link to a phone number ex

```
<a href="tel:9999999999">Call me</a>
```

When you click this you're able to call from a browser, using this concept is it possible to link a phone number to Zendesk talk?

Where if you click the link it will open that phone number up in zendesk talk and they can call? I unfortunately can't find anything online about this after hours of research.

Thanks!

Comment: Is the link being put in a Zendesk App, or in a ticket comment, or a different location?

Comment: @JimmyLong 3rd party website.

Comment: interesting concept, but may be a bit difficult to achieve.  Zendesk doesn't provide a native method to make calls via URL, so it seems there would need to be some customisations with the Zendesk Apps Framework to be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to replicate the behavior of an app like Zoom or Skype, then I don't see it as possible at this time as Zendesk doesn't have a native App, nor do they provide an API to place a call.  You could post in their [product feedback forum](https://support.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/360000029887-Talk-Product-Feedback-) to request this feature.